# Проблема сборки JavaFX приложения

Tags: javafx

Создал приложение в IDEA Intellij 16 на JavaFX, которое компилируется и запускается нормально. Но при попытке сборки приложения  через "Artifact-JavaFX Application" вылетает ошибка:

> "Error:Java FX Packager:BUILD FAILED Error reading project file
>   C:\Users\Программист.IdeaIC15\system\compile-server_temp_\build0.xml:
>   Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence. Total time: 0 seconds".

Проблема с кодировкой, гуглил, но решения пока не нашел. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась установкой новой 16 версии Idea по пути не содержащем кириллицу.